is it possible to use django-push-notifications[FCM] for both android/ios? (if both apps configured in firebase)
I want to use django-push-notifications library for push notifications. My mobile app part configured firebase for both android and ios. In library's documentations they separated logic and configuration of gcm and apns devices. Can I use just GCMDevice for both android and ios devices (to save them, send message) as it is already configured in firebase? Or should I configure apns in django also as it is mentioned in documentation
from firebase_admin import auth

# Initialize the default app (either use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, or pass a firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate instance)
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()

PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
        "APNS_CERTIFICATE": "/path/to/your/certificate.pem",
        "APNS_TOPIC": "com.example.push_test",
        "WNS_PACKAGE_SECURITY_ID": "[your package security id, e.g: 'ms-app://e-3-4-6234...']",
        "WNS_SECRET_KEY": "[your app secret key, e.g.: 'KDiejnLKDUWodsjmewuSZkk']",
        "WP_PRIVATE_KEY": "/path/to/your/private.pem",
        "WP_CLAIMS": {'sub': "mailto:development@example.com"}
}


If so, how to do it properly?
